# Ethernet card failed after the installed ubuntu 14.04 on two PC's

Tags: windows-7, networking, ubuntu, ethernet

I've created ubuntu-14.04 image and restoring on disk and Motherboard model is *GIGABYTE GA-H61M-WW* with this Ethernet controller:

> Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit
>   Ethernet Controller (rev 06)

Now issue is that, as Ubuntu boots up, the link light will go off Ubuntu reports *cable is disconnected* and *ethtool* result:

```
Link Detection: no
```

For this, too many help over the Internet and following many forums but not getting solution yet!

Main issue:
After attached Ubuntu disk, then Switched back to windows 7 disk which was already worked Ethernet card but Now showing *Ethernet unplugged* !

So that reinstall drivers and boot with Linux Live OS but Ethernet not working..., I performed same on two same model PC's and facing same network card issues! So I don't want to performed on another PCs.

Everything are fine like cables, switchs and connectors...

My question is, in built Ethernet is physically failed by Ubuntu on both machine?

How can first solve this issue in windows 7 and after Ubuntu?

Comment: Perhaps your ethernet cable is defective?

Comment: Nop I have tested with lan tester and it was worked before one hour ago, also try to connect directly to laptop

Comment: What is your setup? Are you directly connected to a router, do you use a switch as a surrogate?

Comment: between switch and changes port and switch also,

Comment: What does your LAN Tester tell you that lets you know that it's actually correct for internet? Again, your ethernet cable could be defective / borked. Are any other computers that connect to this switch online / able to access internet?

Comment: It is possible to fail network card by os or drivers ????????

Comment: In short, very unlikely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44801/discussion-between-var-firstname-and-serverninja).

Comment: Everything is fine like cables,switch, lan tester showing right results

Comment: [**Let us continue this discussion in chat.**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44801/discussion-between-var-firstname-and-serverninja)